# When to increase VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE?

Tags: centos, varnish

I use Varnish 4 on CentOS6.6. Storage is set to malloc. Storage size is set to 1G.

Now my question is, how to check if it's enough or should I increase the value of storage size? I know that there is **varnishstat -1** command, but i'm not entirely sure what to look for? I would like to avoid situation when 1GB storage will be not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `n_lru_nuked`. If that is larger than zero then - to make space for new objects - Varnish had to remove old objects before their TTL expired. This is either bad cache design (when caching everything for 10 years) or simply there is not enough space.